# Make phone calls from a Drupal site

Tags: 7

When looking at a user's profile page, I'd like to be able to make a phone call to the user whose profile I'm viewing.  Is this possible in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `tel:` or `callto:` href identifiers depending on the method of your phone call (Skype uses `callto:`, mobiles that support this feature will use `tel:`.

For example, if the number is 123-456-789, your link would look like one of the following:

```
<a href="callto:123-456-789">Call this user</a>
```

or

```
<a href="tel:123-456-789">Call this user</a>
```

Check [this](http://webdev-il.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-make-html-link-to-call-phone.html) (old) blog post for some examples/ideas on implementation.

Comment: Thanks Chapabu, is there any module which uses third party application to make calls.

Comment: Not really..not anything for 7 anyway!  There's the [VoIP API](http://drupal.org/project/voipdrupal) which would probably require some extra work to set up (I've never used it) - it's also still in DEV.

I think your best bet if you're not going to be using the site on mobile to make calls is to add the `callto:` href around the user phone number and use [Skype](http://www.skype.com) to make the calls.